# Short delay inbetween jquery animations. Why?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#car_overtake5").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)}, {duration: 2000, queue: false});
$("#car_overtake5").animate({rotate: '109deg'}, {duration: 2000, queue: true});
$("#car_overtake5").animate({"left":"9872px","top":"4872px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true});
$("#car_overtake5").animate({rotate: '94deg'}, {duration: 250, queue: true});
$("#car_overtake5").animate({"left":"10939px","top":"4948px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true});
```

A car is being animated around a race track. But after each animation it stops for a short amount of time then plays the next one.

How can I make them play fluently without delay?

Edit: Changed easing to linear and now there is no delay.

Comment: Please use `var car = $("#car_overtake5");` or chain the object. There is no need to keep doing the DOM lookup and making it a jQuery object.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to demonstrate it?

Comment: @BradM, or just chain `.animate` calls one after another.

Comment: @Dogbert he did say "or chain the object"

Comment: Making a fiddle to demonstrate is not possible. The project is massive.

Comment: I edited my comment like 5 seconds after writing it @psynnott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default easing is set to "swing", so try changing it to "linear":

```
$("#car_overtake5")
     .animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)}, {duration: 2000, queue: false, easing: "linear"})
     .animate({rotate: '109deg'}, {duration: 2000, queue: true, easing: "linear"})
     .animate({"left":"9872px","top":"4872px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true, easing: "linear"})
     .animate({rotate: '94deg'}, {duration: 250, queue: true, easing: "linear"})
     .animate({"left":"10939px","top":"4948px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true, easing: "linear"});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has to lookup `#car_overtake5` in the DOM each time. This causes a delay, especially in a "massive project" as you stated. Use this:

```
$("#car_overtake5").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)}, {duration: 2000, queue: false})
        .animate({rotate: '109deg'}, {duration: 2000, queue: true})
        .animate({"left":"9872px","top":"4872px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true})
        .animate({rotate: '94deg'}, {duration: 250, queue: true})
        .animate({"left":"10939px","top":"4948px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true});
```

Comment: That lookup wouldn't cause a delay though. The ID selectors maps directly to `getElementById()` which is stupidly fast (although I suppose it *is* possible it's causing the slowdown.

Comment: It is being slowed down because of the animation. From I can see it will animate from point a to point b. But it eases as it slows down instead of keeping a constant speed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, then change your easing to linear!

Comment: Fixed it by changing easing to linear. Works perfect now thanks :)